# C++ TCP send error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c'

Tags: c++, server, tcp, send

I've been trying to make a server in C++. The code compiles and runs, but the function "send" wont work and gives an error as shown in the title. The full error is shown below and is from VSCode.

> Unable to open 'send.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c').

Here is my code. If `send()` is removed from the code, everything works just fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

const int PORT = 5000;
const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 8;


int main(){
    const char* openingMessage = "Welcome!\n";

    struct sockaddr_in address;

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int socketS2G = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //AF_INET is IPv4, SOCK_STREAM is TCP and Protocol value for Internet Protocol(IP), which is 0.
    if(socketS2G == 0){
        std::cout << "Something went wrong!\n";
    } else {
        //bind address to socket objekt
        if(bind(socketS2G, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0){
            std::cout << "Could not bind address and port\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Port now open\n";
            //listen to socket
            if (listen(socketS2G, 3) < 0){
                std::cout << "Can't lisent to socket\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Listening on socket...\n";
                //accept requests from clients
                socklen_t addresslen = sizeof(address);
                while(true){
                    std::cout << "Ready to accept connection\n";
                    accept(socketS2G,(struct sockaddr *)&address,&addresslen);
                    //THE LINE BELOW IS WHERE THINGS BEGIN TO GO WRONG
                    send(socketS2G, openingMessage, strlen(openingMessage), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error only occurs when I try to connect to 127.0.0.1 at port 5000. I use the `telnet` command to connect to my application.

I have a feeling that I might am missing a library, or maybe I am calling the wrong function. I therefore both updated and upgraded my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Not related to your error, but `socket()` returns -1 on failure, not 0. More importantly, you are passing the wrong socket to `send()`, you need to use the socket that is returned by `accept()`, which you are ignoring. And, you need to `close()` both sockets when you are done using them.

Comment: And that fixed my error! Thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like you were running your code inside of a debugger that detected a runtime error in `send()` and was trying to step into the source code for `send()` in `send.c` and thus failed to find the file.